# AngularJs - Pass angular argument to file twig

Tags: angularjs, twig

How can I pass an Angular item to twig file included?

This is my twig file that I want to include:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="[{ hostess.gender == 'F' ? 'Hostess top' : 'Steward top' }]">
    <img src="{{ WBASE }}/assets/img/badge/top-profile.png" class="c-badge [{ extraClass }]"/>
</a>
```

Instead this is my twig file where I render data through angular loop. I need to include a twig file if the condition is true:

```
{% if hostess.top %}
    {% include '_commons/elements/ng-badge-top.twig' with {'hostess': hostess} %}
{% endif %}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you won't be able to do it like that.
Take in consideration that angular is front-side rendered and twig server-side.

If you want to achive that, you will probably have to craete your ng-badge-top.twig as a html and include it with angular using "ng-include".

You can also try something like this:

```
<div ng-if="[{ hostess.top }]"
 ng-include="'{{ path('view_route', { view: 'Content/test.html.twig' }) }}'"></div>
```

This last piece of code will do a call to the server to get a html file and render it. Take in consideration that this controller should serve HTML files, otherwise angular won't be able to process them. Didn't tested it, but if it doesn't work tell me and we will figure out what's wrong.

If those solutions doesn't fit your needs I can give you other options :)